# Any online application for personal life management

Tags: webapp-rec

I am looking for some online app or website where:

1) When I open site I have page divided in hourly intervals and at the end of day I can write what I did on that particular day.

2) I can divide the tasks in categories like sleeping, work, study so that I can see how I am spending my day

3) I can go back on any day in history to see what I did on that day

4) I can see the graphs or charts to see my progress

Searching for long but could not find one. Google Calendar is but I can't make categories in that.

ToDoList doesn't work on daily basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nearest match to your requirements I could find was http://www.inboxjournal.com/

This lets you

- post journal entries per day
- tag entries so you could tag them as work, study etc
- view history
- post entries as private or public

However, it doesn't enable you to split them by hourly intervals or view charts.

Answer (score -2):

- [Life Manager Pro](http://www.lifemanagerpro.com/)
- [My Life Organized](http://www.mylifeorganized.net/)

Comment: This isn't useful. _Why_ do these apps satisfy the OP's requirements?